# Weekly Maintenance Server Using Cron Job

Tags: ubuntu

I'm regularly maintain my servers using this command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean && sudo reboot
```

And I'm executing it manually every week. And now I'm thinking to make a cron job to do it. But, sometimes I got this questions during maintenance :

[image]

[image]

How to automatically select Yes and click default option given when this run using cronjob?

thank you...

Comment: Or use this approach : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates